# const {tokens}, Unexpected token 'const'?

Tags: node.js, api, npm, oauth-2.0

I am implementing google oauth2 using `googleapis`into my react native mobile app along with a nodejs api for generating user Id's and other information. When I run npm start in my api from vscode I get this error:

```
const {tokens} = await url.getToken(code)
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
```

I am not sure what the issue is as the code is straight from the library and I have tried putting it in a function with no luck either. I am pretty new to react native and would love some help. Code:

```
const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

async function refreshToken() {
  oauth2Client.on("tokens", (tokens) => {
    if (tokens.refresh_token) {
      // store the refresh_token in my database!
      console.log(tokens.refresh_token);
    }
    console.log(tokens.access_token);
  });
}
```

Comment: What version of nodejs?  What comes before this line of code?

Comment: node version v12.18.2, before this line was an implementation for other functions from the library to generate the auth url.

Comment: Well, I would guess that some sort of syntax error earlier before this is what is causing the interpreter not to expect a `const` here.  We need to see a larger code context (with nothing missing) to offer help for that.